# What is a computer?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have many questions in meta about what 'retro' means, but fewer on what 'computing' is.

In the [on-topic help](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we refer to 'computing equipment' without defining.

We sometimes have questions that related to devices which might contain microchips, but are not necessarily computers. For example, games consoles, pocket calculators or cars.

I would define a computer as a device that can be, or is intended to be, programmed by its end user. This would include any device from a mainframe to a programmable calculator to a microchip, but might exclude devices such as mobile phones, pocket games consoles, Simon...

This overlaps a bit with questions about computer games vs video or arcade games. I don't have any problem with including computer games, as with any type of software. This definition would exclude arcade games and video games (e.g. Nintendo).

Could the on-topic help be updated to define 'computing equipment' more clearly?

Comment: Related: <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/>

Comment: Also related: <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/47>

Comment: Calculators and consoles have been discussed here before.  Mechanical calculators were left as an unkown - https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/276.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered adequately at https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-constitutes-computing

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you, that is the same question that I linked to in the previous comment.

Comment: [There's a useful definition here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Ladybird-How-Works/dp/072140619X).  And the time is about right for RC:SE.