# Is Intel Itanium on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Intel Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) is probably more-or-less "legacy" now, like the z80 or m68k not what you expect to see inside a computer that's in current mainstream use. That's the impression I got.

But it's rather recent, so I was wondering if my questions about it would be on-topic here or maybe better off on one of the sister sites

Answer (score 2):

If we follow the criteria given in [What constitutes "retro"?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) (which aren’t necessarily definitive of course), Merced would qualify as retro, but Itanium 2 and later wouldn’t. Kittson (no relation) came out last year so Itanium is still current. I know of a few ongoing installations, all running HP operating systems (HPUX, OpenVMS or NonStop OS).

I’m not sure *which* sister site would be most appropriate.