# Moving out of beta?

Tags: discussion, support

It may be a good idea to refine the site, as I'm kind of unsure of the policy decisions you've made here (in meta),

Consider filling out these two FAQ's (which is pretty routine on SE),

- https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: We need to decide what goes in them first! :-) If anyone has any suggestions, please post them as answers so they can be voted on and improved.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Moving a StackExchange site out of beta status depends mainly on two things.

---

### Having enough questions

A site's questions drives all of the other mechanisms of StackExchange: answers, votes, reputation, moderation, and so on.  It puts the site on more search engine results.  And as the blog post says, it

> produces high quality questions and answers that *make the internet better*. That’s our mission. That’s the driving goal behind all our sites.

Although there is no strict minimum number of questions to get out of beta, it looks like 10,000 is a desirable number.  That's enough to demonstrate that a site is viable and will continue to draw questions in the future.  *RC* currently has only 1,768 questions.  Think about that.

To that end, I would recommend:

1. Expand the on-topic options.  "Restoration, preservation and maintenance" is waaaaay too narrow.  As JdeBP [pointed out](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/634/10260), it should also include "design" and "history".  The inclusion of game consoles has helped in this respect.  Add more things that are on-topic.
2. Try harder to improve bad questions, instead of closing them.  Have a policy of waiting 48 hours before closing a question.  During the first 24 hours, add comments suggesting how the poster can improve the question.  During the second 24 hours, edit the question yourself to improve it.
3. Similarly for duplicate questions, try to find a way to turn it into a new unique question.  During the first 24 hours, comment with a link to the old question and a suggested way to improve it.  During the second 24 hours, edit the question yourself to improve it.
4. Of course, a post that is spam, abusive, or not at all a question should just be closed.
5. If one question gives you an idea for another, post it.
6. Remember to be nice, so people come back.  Fortunately for this particular SE site, this seems to be the case.

---

### Having enough users who can edit and close questions

The blog post also talks about the importance of having enough users with 3k reputation.  This is because when a site graduates to final status, the threshold for editing posts raises from 750 to 2000, and the threshold for closing posts raises from 500 to 3000.  The blog post specifically warns about sites that do not have enough of these users active can become unmanaged, because they have few users to edit or close posts.

*RC* currently has 30 users at 3k and 47 users at 2k reputation.  How many of these users have been active during the past month?

To this end, I recommend:

7. Don't forget to vote.  Users need upvotes to get above 3k.  I'm definitely not saying to upvote everything without reason; that defeats the point of voting (to differentiate good things from bad things) and [can be automatically reversed](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).  But if you do find something useful, upvote it.
8. Instead of downvoting, consider just leaving a comment on how to improve the post.
9. When one person answers all the questions, it makes it harder for more users to get to 3k reputation.  So, if you are already past 3k, consider waiting 12 or 24 hours before answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

Fair enough, my suggestion is always to create a standard based specifically on *content* and lacking subjective qualifiers. Avoid terms like *"basic"* (in use on dba.se), and *"expert"* or *"commercial"* (which is how server fault defines themselves). These are all horrible ideas that create confusion and stagnate the communities.

- If it's the subject of the question is technical in nature and has faced **20 years** of near-continuous dwindling market share having already seen its prime in its respective area, it's on topic here. Architectural and historical questions that date to the period are also welcome.

That's perfectly fine, it's also **very fun.** At least in my opinion. It directs users to no other site and welcomes users here with nothing more than a quick consideration "is it old enough, and has it fallen into relative disuse." Intuitively that's what I think of when I think retrocomputing.

The real benefit to this sufficiently vague mission is that it permits other sites like StackOverflow, SuperUser, and Server Fault to start migrating questions your way. And, it establishes a relatively clear basis for you to send misguided questions back. Something I truly wish other sites (specifically DBA.SE) would establish.

I highly suggest checking out this post, (and voting for Jon's answer). Don't make the same mistakes.

- https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/should-basic-sql-questions-be-allowed

Comment: Erm... This question is extremely broad; I didn't notice that at first. When I suggested asking here I thought you were just going to mention the FAQ posts. I think you should post your suggestion on [What constitutes retro?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/278), where we were making _that_ decision. Seeing as you don't know where all of these things are, we really do need to put together an FAQ.

Comment: Given that the process of graduation is progressive nowadays, we don't need to rush.  As wizzwizz4 says, we already have the "What constitutes retro" question that is an ongoing definition of the site.